ASP.Net Identity OAuth login - 2 different UseGoogleAuthentication
I am using ASP.NET Standard (not .NET Core)
At startup I have this :
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
            {
                ClientId = "client",
                ClientSecret = "secret"
            });

I would like to change my clientId based on the UserAgent.
Problem 1 is:
on Start up the Context.UserAgent is null
I have tried an async attempt at startup but it calls it on every page load and this is not efficient:
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {

                var userAgent = context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"]; 
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(userAgent) && userAgent.Contains("xxxx"))
                {
                    app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
                    {
                        ClientId = "client id 2",
                        ClientSecret = "secret2"
                    });

                }
                else
                {
                    app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
                    {
                        ClientId = "client id 1",
                        ClientSecret = "secret 1"
                    });

                }

                await next.Invoke();
            });

Problem 2 is:
at run time I cant change the app.UseGoogleAuthentication.. because there is no app Context.
how can I make this work.

You should only have one client id for your prod system and one for dev you shouldnt be switching like this they should be configured as env vars

for ios running as an App, unfortunately a standard Google client is not sufficient, you have to have a ios application type.. this means 2 clientids... would love to hear if there is an alternative, I couldnt find a way to make the std OAuth client work for ios app
